# How to get Channel object in Spring boot AMQP and create a Exchange of type "x-consistent-hash"

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

The examples mentioned to create a Consistent hashing exchange in the [RabbitMQ Consistent Hasing Github](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-consistent-hash-exchange) uses Channel to create exchanges :

```
private static String CONSISTENT_HASH_EXCHANGE_TYPE = "x-consistent-hash";
...
Channel ch = conn.createChannel();
...
ch.exchangeDeclare("e1", CONSISTENT_HASH_EXCHANGE_TYPE, true, false, null);
```

[image: Exchange details]

---

---

I tried creating consistent hash exchange using arguments but it was not working :

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class AMQPConfig {

    public static final String QUEUENAME = "consistentHashing-Q1";
    public static final String EXCHANGENAME = "consistentHashing-DE1";
    public static final String RK = "consistentHashing-RK1";


    @Bean
    public Queue queue() {
        return QueueBuilder.nonDurable(QUEUENAME).autoDelete().build();
    }

    @Bean
    public DirectExchange directExchange()  {
        return ExchangeBuilder.directExchange(EXCHANGENAME).autoDelete().withArgument("Type", "x-consistent-hash").build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Binding binding(Queue queue, Exchange exchange)    {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange).with(RK).noargs();
    }
}
```

[image: Exchange not working]

---

1. Would like to know how to get Channel object in the Spring boot
2. AMQP? How to create a Consistent hash exchange in Spring boot AMQP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was able to create Consistent Hashing Exchange in Spring boot AMQP using the below code :

```
@Bean
public CustomExchange customExchange()  {
    CustomExchange customExchange = new CustomExchange(EXCHANGENAME, "x-consistent-hash", false, true);
    customExchange.addArgument("hash-header", "client-id");
    return customExchange;
}
```

Comment: Good answer; I forgot about `CustomExchange`.

Comment: Yes Gary. It was a hard find for me too.

Answer (score 1):

Spring AMQP has no mechanism to declare custom exchanges as `@Bean` definitions, but you can use a `RabbitTemplate` to get a channel to declare it yourself.

```java
Exchange.DeclareOk = rabbitTemplate.execute(channel -> channel.exchangeDeclare(...));
```

Comment: Thanks Gary. May I know where did you find this information?

Comment: I am the project lead.